# Getting String from JSON file Java

Tags: java, json

I want to read a JSON File, using "JSON SIMPLE" API.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray a = null;
try {
    a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\data\\data.json"));
} catch (IOException | ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

for (Object o : a) {
    JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) o;

    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Test");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

My JSON FILE:

```
{
    "Test" : {
        "Tenorhorn" : "2",
        "Tuba" : "2",
        "Posaune" : "3",
        "Schreibweise" : "B",
        "SonstigeInst" : "",
        "Author" : "tesaf",
        "Wertung" : "1",
        "Trompete" : "2",
        "Partitur" : "Partitur",
        "Path" : ""
    }
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
"Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 237."

At position 237 is: `               } catch (IOException | ParseException e1) {
```

`

Comment: Please show us your complete json file.

Comment: `position 237` refers to the JSON file, not the Java file. Are you sure you're indeed loading the file you added to the question? The file being loaded should have at least 237 lines to throw this Exception.

Comment: The error message you posted makes it look like you're trying to parse Java code with a json parser.  Also, the json you posted has no arrays in it, it's just a normal object.

Comment: Are you using an IDE or using command line? Because the error you wrote is not a json error. It is a compiling error. That probably means there are some " { " that does not followed with " } ". If you would use an ide you wouldn't be able to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 237."
At position 237 is: `               } catch (IOException | ParseException e1) {
```

Sounds like

```
} catch (IOException | ParseException e1) {
```

is unexpected in a Json file

Answer (score 0):

In the first place the JSON provided by you is a JSONObject and not an array. To parse it, the following code block will work..

```
JSONParser  parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject a = null;
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:\\data\\data.json");
        a = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileReader);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }        
     System.out.println(a.get("Test"));
```

Output will be : {"Tenorhorn":"2","Tuba":"2","Posaune":"3","Schreibweise":"B","SonstigeInst":"","Author":"tesaf","Trompete":"2","Wertung":"1","Partitur":"Partitur","Path":""}

And to answer your question about array, you can use a Json array instead of single Json object.

eg:

```
[{
"Tenorhorn": "2",
"Tuba": "2",
"Posaune": "3",
"Schreibweise": "B",
"SonstigeInst": "",
"Author": "tesaf",
"Wertung": "1",
"Trompete": "2",
"Partitur": "Partitur",
"Path": ""
```

}]

Your code will be..

```
JSONArray a = null;
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:\\data\\data.json");
        a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(fileReader);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Object o : a) {
        JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) o;

        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
```

One more thing to remember is IOException | ParseException e1 - Multi-catch parameters are not allowed if you are using JDK below 1.7